# Catching exception spawns new process

Tags: c#

It seems everytime an exception is caught, a new process instance is created. But it doesn't happen for my friend. What can be causing this?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("Number of process instances: " + Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length);
      try {
        int b = 0;
        int a = 1 / b;
      } catch {
      };
      Console.WriteLine("Number of process instances: " + Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

The code results in the following output:

```
Number of process instances: 1
Number of process instances: 2
```

However i've passed the code to a friend. He gets the following output:

```
Number of process instances: 1
Number of process instances: 1
```

I'm using VS2017

Comment: Or maybe your computer has 2 process with same name ?

Comment: @ThierryV Only after the exception is thrown?

Comment: Are you running it in the debugger? Or from the command line?

Comment: what happens if you do something that doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: Are you sure? Are you still facing this issue? @Thierry V If computer has two process with same name then it would show value 2 in both the console statements.

Comment: what version of .Net framework you are on?

Comment: Was running in debugger, friend was running in debugger as well. If there is no exception, a second process is not spawned. the two output lines are identical. The issue also comes if the exception is of another type, not only for arithmetic error. Think its .Net 4.5.1. Not at computer so cant say for sure.

Comment: @MattBurland When i run without debugger i don't get this issue!